# Why are NAs introduced when I convert character dates to date format?

Tags: r, date, date-conversion

I have some dates:

```
      [,1]           
 [1,] "March 4 2018" 
 [2,] "March 11 2018"
 [3,] "March 18 2018"
 [4,] "March 26 2018"
 [5,] "April 2 2018" 
 [6,] "April 9 2018" 
 [7,] "April 16 2018"
 [8,] "April 23 2018"
 [9,] "April 30 2018"
[10,] "March 4 2018" 
[11,] "March 11 2018"
[12,] "March 18 2018"
[13,] "March 26 2018"
[14,] "April 2 2018" 
[15,] "April 9 2018" 
[16,] "April 16 2018"
[17,] "April 23 2018"
[18,] "April 30 2018"
```

I want to convert these to date format (using `anytime`) but it results in some NA values:

```
[1] NA                        "2018-03-11 01:00:00 GMT" "2018-03-18 01:00:00 GMT" "2018-03-26 01:00:00 BST" NA                       
 [6] NA                        "2018-04-16 01:00:00 BST" "2018-04-23 01:00:00 BST" "2018-04-30 01:00:00 BST" NA                       
[11] "2018-03-11 01:00:00 GMT" "2018-03-18 01:00:00 GMT" "2018-03-26 01:00:00 BST" NA                        NA                       
[16] "2018-04-16 01:00:00 BST" "2018-04-23 01:00:00 BST" "2018-04-30 01:00:00 BST"
```

This is the command I used:

```
library(anytime)
anytime(df$date)
```

Why is this happening and how do I rectify it?

Comment: Because it must be expecting day to be a two-digit value? You can try `as.Date('March 4 2018', format = '%B %d %Y')`?

Comment: It's impossible to know without knowing the command you used. However, `as.POSIXct(x, format='%B %d %Y')` (as well `as.Date(...)`) worked without problem for me.

Comment: You could do `anytime(sub("\\b(\\d)\\b", "0\\1", "April 9 2018"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following people's suggestions, `as.POSIXct(df$date, format='%B %d %Y')` has worked for me here.

Thank you all.